The Blob URL of the pdf document loading fails in the latest version of the ng2-pdfjs-viewer when using CDN for the pdfjs sources
We use the CDN server to store sources for the pdfjs's web and build folders and then setup ng2-pdfjs-viewer like this:
<ng2-pdfjs-viewer #externalPdfViewer
                    [hidden]="error()"
                    viewerId="DocumentPdfViewer"
                    [viewerFolder]="https://cdn.some.url/pdfjs"
                    (onDocumentLoad)="onDocumentLoad()"></ng2-pdfjs-viewer>

then loading pdf and set it as Blob URL
const res = await this.getPdfAsBlobUrl(downloadUrl);
this.externalPdfViewer().pdfSrc = res as Blob;
this.externalPdfViewer().refresh();

It worked fine with the previous version of the ng2-pdfjs-viewer, but the current version uses IFRAME and fails to load the BLOB URL, it's blocked by the browser because of different domains I assume.
The question is: has someone resolved such a problem? Is it possible to force ng2-pdfjs-viewer to not use IFRAME or send the File in a different way other than BLOB URL? (cannot just put the file URL and let the library load it by itself because of too complicated document loading procedure)

OK, I have no problems with the Blob URL, it's IFRAME that breaks everything for me... It would be just great if the pdf content and controls were rendered right inside the  container, without viewer.html and all the CORS problems I have with this...
